# Defining a "narrowized" font for \setmonofont{}

Tags: fonts, koma-script, typewriter

Because of Corporate Design rules, I need to use the font *SourceCodePro* for monospaced text and *Arial* for plain text. Using KOMA Script, I declared

```
\setmainfont{Arial}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{\familydefault}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}
```

Unfortunately, the monospaced stands out too much (for my taste) when used for single words or lines of a paragraph. Other occurences might be tolerated but are not appealing. To reduce the pain, I use the macro

```
\newcommand{\mono}[1]{\texttt{\protect\scalebox{.9}[1.0]{#1}}}
```

which works well for plain text as expected but leads to problems

- when used in *hyperref*'s `\url` macro (`\mono{\url{...}}` works if it's acceptable to lose the ability to break the text but `\url{\mono{...}` does not) and more annoyingly,
- does not work at all when used in *listing*'s `lstlisting` environment.

Instead of trying to solve both issues somehow, I hope there is a way to pass the information to scale the font to `\setmonofont{}` and thus declare all occurrences of *SourceCodePro* to be narrow.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the mono font with the option `FakeStretch` (manual of `fontspec`, example 17).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Source Code Pro}[FakeStretch=0.9]

\newfontfamily{\scp}{Source Code Pro}% for comparing

\begin{document}

Some words in Arial and \texttt{some in shrinked mono font}

Some words in Arial and {\scp some in unshrinked mono font}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is _awesome_! Do you wanna marry me? :-D

Comment: On the other hand, this leaves problems with _hyperref_'s `\url` macro. The url macro typesets the fakestretched letters, but uses the plain letter space which is too wide. My workaround would is `\href{url}{\ttfamily url}`.